# On my zsh installation error: colors: function definition file not found

Tags: oh-my-zsh

I happened to these ignoring message after I have newly installed the zsh and on my zsh!. The version of zsh is 5.0.7, which is compiled on centos 6.6.

```
/home/henry/.oh-my-zsh/lib/theme-and-appearance.zsh:2: colors: function definition file not found
/home/henry/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh:69: compinit: function definition file not found
```

I have previously successfully installed on my zsh! On multiple centos machines, however I have never encountered this error.